# Function into dynamics selectBoxes which works once, twice or never. React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, function

I have a form with dynamic selectBoxes. Depending on the result of the first one, I call a function whose result will go into the second selectBox.

I found solutions:

Apparently onClick is not working on the option tag, so I put my function in the onChange of the select tag.
Or
I used useEffect to call the function when the variable changes.

These solutions above work, but my problem is that it works once, sometimes twice but not more. I have to reload the page and it doesn't work for all of that.

If anyone would like to dive into my code and tell me why it doesn't work every time.

Thank you.

the variables componentOriginName, componentTargetName and the functions getComponentOriginNames, getComponentTargetNames come from redux.

```
    const [relationType, setRelationType] = useState({
        type: props.type,
    });

    const [newRelation, setNewRelation] = useState({
        componentOriginType: "",
        componentOriginName: "",
        componentTargetType: "",
        componentTargetName: "",
        data: "",
    });
```

the Form :

```
<div className='container--info--tuple'>
                    <div className='group--input'>
                        <select
                            name='componentOriginType'
                            onChange={handleChange}
                            value={newRelation.componentOriginType}
                            required>
                            <option value=''></option>
                            {props.components &&
                                props.components.map((component, i) => {
                                    return (
                                        <option key={i} value={component.name}>
                                            {component.name}
                                        </option>
                                    );
                                })}
                        </select>
                        <span className='floating--label--select required'>
                            Composant origine
                        </span>
                    </div>
                    <div className='group--input'>
                        <select
                            name='componentOriginName'
                            onChange={handleChange}
                            value={newRelation.componentOriginName}
                            required>
                            <option value=''></option>
                            {props.componentOriginName &&
                                props.componentOriginName.map((component, i) => {
                                    return (
                                        <option key={i} value={component.name}>
                                            {component.name}
                                        </option>
                                    );
                                })}
                        </select>
                        <span className='floating--label--select required'>
                            Nom du composant d'origine
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className='container--info--tuple'>
                    <div className='group--input'>
                        <select
                            name='type'
                            onChange={handleChangeType}
                            value={relationType.type}
                            required>
                            <option value=''></option>
                            {props.relations.map((relation, i) => {
                                return (
                                    <option key={i} value={relation.name}>
                                        {relation.name}
                                    </option>
                                );
                            })}
                        </select>
                        <span className='floating--label--select required'>Relation</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className='container--info--tuple'>
                    <div className='group--input'>
                        <select
                            name='componentTargetType'
                            onChange={handleChange}
                            value={newRelation.componentTargetType}
                            required>
                            <option value=''></option>
                            {props.components &&
                                props.components.map((component, i) => {
                                    return (
                                        <option key={i} value={component.name}>
                                            {component.name}
                                        </option>
                                    );
                                })}
                        </select>
                        <span className='floating--label--select required'>
                            Composant cible
                        </span>
                    </div>
                    <div className='group--input'>
                        <select
                            name='componentTargetName'
                            onChange={handleChange}
                            value={newRelation.componentTargetName}
                            required>
                            <option value=''></option>
                            {props.componentTargetName &&
                                props.componentTargetName.map((component, i) => {
                                    return (
                                        <option key={i} value={component.name}>
                                            {component.name}
                                        </option>
                                    );
                                })}
                        </select>
                        <span className='floating--label--select required'>
                            Nom du composant cible
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

and the functions with my differents tests commented :

```
    const handleChange = (event) => {
        setNewRelation({
            ...newRelation,
            [event.target.name]: event.target.value,
        });
        if (event.target.name === "componentOriginType") {
            propsGetComponentOriginNames(event.target.value);
        } else if (event.target.name === "componentTargetType") {
            propsGetComponentTargetNames(event.target.value);
        }
    };

    // =======================================================================

    // const test = (type) => {
    //  props.getComponentOriginNames(type);
    // };
    // const handleChangeOrigin = (event) => {
    //  test(event.target.value);
    //  setNewRelation({
    //      ...newRelation,
    //      [event.target.name]: event.target.value,
    //  });
    // };

    // const handleChangeTarget = (event) => {
    //  props.getComponentTargetNames(event.target.value);
    //  setNewRelation({
    //      ...newRelation,
    //      [event.target.name]: event.target.value,
    //  });
    // };
    // =======================================================================

    const propsGetComponentOriginNames = props.getComponentOriginNames;
    const propsGetComponentTargetNames = props.getComponentTargetNames;

    // useEffect(() => {
    //  propsGetComponentOriginNames(newRelation.componentOriginType);
    // }, [
    //  propsGetComponentOriginNames,
    //  newRelation.componentOriginType,
    //  relationType.type,
    // ]);

    // useEffect(() => {
    //  propsGetComponentTargetNames(newRelation.componentTargetType);
    // }, [
    //  newRelation.componentTargetType,
    //  propsGetComponentTargetNames,
    //  relationType.type,
    // ]);

    // =======================================================================
```